# Jenkins not running istanbul JS code coverage tool

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, istanbul, teaspoon

I am using Teaspoon + Istanbul JS code coverage tool for Ruby project,which has more JS code in it.

I have installed istanbul using $ npm install -g istanbul commend on the jenkins box.

If the run bundle exec teaspoon, it works fine on local and producing JS codo coverage report nicely.

But when i run the same command thru jenkins shell, its not  produce any report.

$istanbul help throw command not found on the jenkins

Comment: Make sure you have installed npm on the Jenkins box and execute it from your shell commands.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed npm on the Jenkins box and execute it from your shell commands.